# Which algorithm works under the hood for "contains" function of swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sequence, higher-order-functions

"Contains" function of Sequence is very useful, but I want to ask which algorithm exactly does the work for us underneath this function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Swift is open source you can see from the [`contains` implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L511) that it iterates over the sequence until it finds an element that matches the predicate, in which case it returns true, and that it returns false if it reaches the end of the sequence before finding a matching element:

```
public func contains(
  where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool
) rethrows -> Bool {
  for e in self {
    if try predicate(e) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift is open source, you can see all the source code here https://github.com/apple/swift/

The source for `Sequence.swift` is here https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swi

`SequenceAlgorithms.swift` is here 
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift